# Specify to load index.html file for every request in apache config file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I have a React application hosted on my server and I need to always load `index.html` file for every request users make.

Let's say that I have a website that has the address `xyz.com`, and the root directory contains the React build files, including this `index.html` file. There are many routes that users can specify to access to certain parts of the website, for example to register on the website they can access `xyz.com/register`. So, what I want to accomplish is instruct server to always serve this `index.html` every time users access my site, even though they are visiting different routes of the website.

So I'm assuming that this is something that I can set up in the .conf file for the website, and if it is, can you please let me know how I can achieve it?

Comment: What to you mean by "to always load .html file"? Which file? Always the same?

Comment: @arkascha i'm so sorry for not including enough details, can you please look into this again I have updated the question so that you can understand it clearly. Thanks!

Comment: Though I am also not sure which ".conf file" you refer to I assume that the answer @Pandurang posted below will point you into the right direction.

Comment: that is the apache configuration file for the website

Comment: I suggest that you try to express more precise what files you actually refer to. Phrases like "the .conf file" are miss leading. Please understand that different distributions use different file system layouts, especially the apache http server configuration is typically spread over many many files. So why not refer to it as the apache configuration files but use a phrase like "the .conf file"? You also should redoncider that the old fashioned "file name extension" (file names containing a dot followed by a two or three character code) is exactly that: completely outdated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there any way to change the apache configuration file for the website to have that behavior without having a .htaccess file.

Comment: You can use this configuration inside VirtualHost.